# Why is Firestore querying all my references?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Recently, when I enabled OfflinePersistence, I noticed that too much documents were saved. I wondered why and activated log level 'debug' in order to analyse what was happening when I queried few documents.

To give you background, my database looks like this :

```
{
  recurrences: {
    day: integer
    slots: array of references to documents of slots
    [...]
  }
  slots: {
    date: date
    recurrence: reference to a document of recurrences
    [...]
  }
}
```

My query gather all slots in a date range :

```
this.$firestore.collection('slots')
        .where('start', '>=', moment(currentWeek).toDate())
        .where('start', '<', moment(currentWeek).add(7, 'days').toDate())
```

But because each Slot document have a reference to a Recurrence document, Firestore seems to directly query the corresponding Recurrence document, as I can see in the logs :

```
[2018-11-26T08:54:00.129Z]  @firebase/firestore: Firestore (5.5.0) [Connection]: WebChannel received: {"documentChange":{"document":{"name":"projects/projet/databases/(default)/documents/slots/ARnClPDr03bHI6ZI5V5","fields":{"start":{"timestampValue":"2018-12-01T16:00:00Z"},"status":{"stringValue":"RESTRICTED"},"participants_count":{"integerValue":"0"},"recurrence":{"referenceValue":"projects/projet/databases/(default)/documents/recurrences/31shOUDlY9Sq3COthxSu"},"duration":{"integerValue":"1"},"participants":{"mapValue":{}},"title":{"stringValue":"ville"}},"createTime":"2018-11-25T21:27:24.844292Z","updateTime":"2018-11-25T21:27:56.743319Z"},"targetIds":[4]}}
[...]
 [2018-11-26T08:54:00.207Z]  @firebase/firestore: Firestore (5.5.0) [Connection]: WebChannel sending: {"database":"projects/projet/databases/(default)","addTarget":{"documents":{"documents":["projects/projet/databases/(default)/documents/recurrences/H2NLe394D6heR0Zs178o"]},"targetId":6}}
```

More logs can be found there : https://pastebin.com/V5rpq6Ya

And because a Recurrence document store a lot of Slot referrences, Firestore continue to query **all** related Slot documents...

To resume, a single small query that should return me some results is returning me the whole database.

**How can I tell Firestore to stay shallow and to not query references documents ?**

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: What do you mean through `all my references`? You say that it returns all the reference within `slots` array?

Comment: I don't see how you have determined that all the references in a document are being automatically fetched (you are showing really long log lines that are difficult to read).  When a document is fetched, it should not fetch all its references as well.

Comment: @AlexMamo : yes, exactly :)

Comment: @DougStevenson : I provided only a very small part of my logs. In the logs I provided, you can see that directly after Firestore received the Slot document, it sends a new query to gather the linked Recurrence document

Comment: It's not clear to me that's what's going on in the logs you're showing.  Can you format the logs so they're easier to read (it's JSON), and also explain how the logs prove that what you're saying is true?

Comment: You should definitely do, what Doug asked you.

Comment: @DougStevenson : Here is a PasteBin of more lines from my logs https://pastebin.com/V5rpq6Ya. My real logs contains thousands of lines for this relatively simple query

Comment: I'm not sure anyone is going to filter through all your logs, and I'm not going to click on it since I'm mobile right now. Your question should contain everything needed *in the question itself* to give someone everything they need to know to answer the question. Your job is to make it easy for us to see what's wrong.

Comment: @DougStevenson I filtered my logs, the link does not contains thousands of lines :) The reason why I used PasteBin is because some lines are hundreds catacters long

Comment: @DougStevenson What the logs show is only that Firestore query a document for each referrence encountered